# How do you make a shape static while the camera moves C++ OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I want to make a maze game, with shapes in the form of a maze and a person walking through ( or a square or something) in 2d. I know how to make the camera move, but what I don't know is how to make the person/square move with the camera. I'm using C++ with OpenGL, and at the moment I'm using freeglut but I realize this isn't the best thing to be using. I'm still a beginner, so if I can do it in freeglut and not have to download anything that would be optimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the answer to my own question. I have already built the quad that takes parameters quadx and quad y for the bottom left vertex. I have built a function that moves the camera based on the key that is pressed, and to have the quad appear to stay with the camera, just have it move the same amount as the camera does.

P.S. Make sure to have the thing you want to move with the camera in view at the starting location of the camera, else it will never be on the screen because it will move away just as much as you look for it.